# Importing space-delimited data into MySQL

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

I have file in the following format:

```
`e00` `e01` `e02` `e03`
`e10` `e11` `e12` `e13
```

Trying to import the data with

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file' INTO TABLE 'foo' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ' ' ENCLOSED BY '`'
```

only seems to get the first 3 fields of each line. Is there a way to load the data without altering the file format?

Comment: Do you get any warnings?

Comment: There's no quotes around the table name, at least on the latest documentation and by the error I got while running your command on my machine. (that's assuming you forgot the last backtick after e13). Also, could you provide the `show create table foo` command output? Maaaybe also `SELECT * FROM foo` after the `LOAD DATA`?. I think you don't have 4 columns on your table. Only asking because I could not reproduce your situation, I got 2 rows with four columns and each value on it.

Comment: What is the line separator (unix\n  or dos\r\n)? Maybe you should include LINES TERMINATED BY 'something-apropriate'.

Answer (score -1):

Let's all jump in the way-back machine to answer a 5-year old question!

The fact that the last item is not being loaded is a big hint.  According to [the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html):

> If LINES TERMINATED BY is an empty string and FIELDS TERMINATED BY is
>   nonempty, lines are also terminated with FIELDS TERMINATED BY.

So, it's looking for a trailing space at the end of the line.

You could add a space to the end of each line in your input file, or try `LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'`